# Once a part of the standard - will boost library lose its boost namespace and will be moved to std?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, standards

Once a Boost library (I have read that ten Boost libs are considered to be a become a part of Standard Library) becomes a part of Standard Library - is it going to keep it's boost namespace or the code will end up in std namespace?

If the latter is the case - how would you workaround that potential namespace clash in your code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The items from Boost libraries that made it to the standard will of course be included in namespace `std`. However, I don't think that their Boost counterpart will change in any way : if we take the example of `bind`, people compiling C++0x will use `std::bind` while people compiling C++03 will keep using `boost::bind`.

I may be wrong, but from my understanding, it's the *concepts* from boost libraries that made it to the standard, not the *exact specifications*. As far as I know, `boost::bind` could very well keep evolving and provide something different from `std::bind` at some point (hell, I haven't read the C++0x standard yet so I don't have the answer, but `std::bind` might already be different from `boost::bind` !).

There is no issue with namespace clash here : each library stands in it own namespace, and you could very well use `std::bind` and `boost::bind` in the same C++0x project.

Comment: ok. I see now. That basically mean that standard will contain a version of a particular boost library as of some date in 2010, while the library itself would continue to be evolving as a part of the boost project. It seems to be then, that a standardized part of the boost will primarily be used by library developers, while people who develop a standalone software would continue to use a boost code from the boost.org.

Comment: No! The standard will not contain any parts of particular boost libraries. In fact this does never happen (and has ever happened before). The central comitee (pun intended) often takes over some concepts which were proposed in boost, but elaborates its own specifications (which admittedly rarely differ from the original ones...) The concrete implementations of the standard library are a completely different thing, though...

Comment: In fact, `boost::bind` and `std::bind` are not exactly equivalent. For example, `boost::bind(strlen, _1) < boost::bind(strlen, _2)` works, but `std::bind(strlen, std::placeholders::_1) < std::bind(strlen, std::placeholders::_2)` does *not* work, because `<` is only overloaded in the `boost::bind` library.

Comment: thanks Paul, the picture is clear now. "concepts" was the word. can you explain the pun in your "central comitee" please (English is not my first language) - if it is not too much of off topic.